# issue with string_agg with distinct in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am getting error for below query. Basically to use `||` & `distinct` together.

```
select string_agg( 'pre' || distinct user.col, 'post')
```

It works fine like this

```
select string_agg( 'pre' || user.col, 'post')
```

& this

```
select string_agg(distinct user.col, 'post')
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
select string_agg(distinct 'pre' || user.col, 'post')
```

As the above will deny the use of an index in the `distinct` aggregation take the `'pre'` out

```
select 'pre' || string_agg(distinct user.col, 'postpre')
```

Comment: This would prepend a single "pre" string to the entire string_agg output, eg `preFIRSTpostSECONDpostTHIRDpost`. The original question (although not very clear) appears to request prepending "pre" to each item included within the aggregation, eg `preFIRSTpostpreSECONDpostpreTHIRDpost`.

Answer (score 4):

The [concat](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html) function can help you.

```
select string_agg(distinct concat('pre',user.col, 'post'), '')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
array_to_string(array_agg(distinct column_name::text), '; ')
```

Will get the job done