# Select just one row for equal parameters and all rows if they differ

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have a database table:

```
| id | account | extra_account | state |special_value
```

I need to select extra_accounts, which are connected with a list of accounts.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE table.account in (111, 222, 333) and table.state = 'WORKS';
```

```
|id  | account         | extra_account     | state         |special_value
—-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|100 |111              |111-1              |WORKS          |1
|200 |111              |111-2              |WORKS          |1
|300 |222              |222-1              |WORKS          |2
|400 |333              |333-1              |WORKS          |3
|500 |333              |333-2              |WORKS          |4
```

I have to concatenate extra_accounts in one String separated by a comma.

If an account has two or more extra_accounts and their special_value are the same I have to take one extra_accounts, no matter which.
So for `id=100` and `id=200` I have to take just one extra_account - 111-1 or 111-2, as their special_values are equal.

If an account has two or more extra_accounts and their special_value are different I have to take all of them.
So for `id=400` and `id=500`, I need both - 333-1 and 333-2, as their special_values are 3 and 4.

The final result should be:

```
|string_agg
|text
—----
|111-1, 222-1, 333-1, 333-2
```

I know that I can concat values by using:

```
SELECT  string_agg(table.extra_account, ', ')
FROM table WHERE table.account in (111, 222, 333) and table.state = 'WORKS';
```

But I didn’t find a way to select all rows if special_values are different and only one row if special_values are equal.

Comment: This one will help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785084/issue-with-string-agg-with-distinct-in-postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what you want per account:

```sql
SELECT account
     , CASE WHEN count(DISTINCT special_value) = 1
            THEN min(extra_account)
            ELSE string_agg(extra_account, ', ')
            END AS special_values
FROM   tbl
WHERE  account IN (111, 222, 333)
AND    state = 'WORKS'
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Wrap the above in a subquery and aggregate:

```sql
SELECT string_agg(special_values, ', ')
FROM (
   SELECT account
        , CASE WHEN count(DISTINCT special_value) = 1
               THEN min(extra_account)
               ELSE string_agg(extra_account, ', ')
               END AS special_values
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  account IN (111, 222, 333)
   AND    state = 'WORKS'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub;
```

Produces your desired result exactly.

If you really want a single `extra_account` per distinct `special_value` (unlike expressed):

```sql
SELECT string_agg(extra_account, ', ')
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT ON (account, special_value) extra_account FROM tbl) sub;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f8b7b2d871f3675a498407e2187ddcac)* - with an added row to show the difference

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

(And why it's [typically faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715134/939860).)

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate a ROW_NUMBER then you can take 1 based on account & special_value.

> ```
> SELECT 
>  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT extra_account, ', ' ORDER BY extra_account) AS extra_accounts
> FROM (
>   SELECT account, extra_account, special_value
>   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account, special_value ORDER BY id) AS rownum
>   FROM "table" t
>   WHERE account IN (111, 222, 333) 
>     AND state = 'WORKS' 
> ) q
> WHERE rownum = 1;
> ```

| extra_accounts |
| --- |
| 111-1, 222-1, 333-1, 333-2 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=059c7eba045d28b1760c04739de77aa4)*

Comment: Clever. But it fails for accounts that have *some*, but not all duplicate special values. See: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d068b80d2c32e501900f6dc8e979e16d)* (Unless the OP didn't specify properly ...)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Well, we'll see what nikiforov comments about it. But that extra special_value 4 shouldn't be taken, as I understand the question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this via the aggregate function `min` on the columns account and special_value.

```
With CTE As (
Select account, special_value, Min(extra_account) As v
From Tbl
Where account In (111, 222, 333) And state = 'WORKS'
Group by account, special_value
)
Select string_agg(v, ',' Order by v)
From CTE
```

Data Output:

| string_agg |
| --- |
| 111-1,222-1,333-1,333-2 |