# Query to return column values as comma separated - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using materialized view in my application.

The query is as follows

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT n.order_id,
  CASE
    WHEN n.customer_billing = TRUE THEN 'AR (Customer Billing)'
    WHEN n.commander = TRUE THEN 'AP (Commander)'
    WHEN n.agent = TRUE THEN 'AP (Agent)'
    ELSE NULL
  END AS finance
FROM
  pt.notes n
 WHERE
 n.order_id = 891090 AND
  (n.customer_billing = TRUE or n.commander = TRUE or n.agent = TRUE)
```

This produces the following output

[image]

Instead of two records, the output of finance column should be comma separated values.

That is the output should be

**AP (Agent), AR (Customer Billing)**

I know aggregate functions can be used here, but not sure how to use when the query has switch cases and all.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: lookup use of `string_Agg()`  I don't recommend denormalizing data like this however.  it's more of a UI Function.  However there are some special circumstances where you may need to...

Comment: This is close to a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:  Seldom is it wise to de-normalize data this way in the database query; Better done in UI.  However, if this is going directly to an aggregated report; it may make sense to do it here... But keep in mind if this ever will need to be separated later; you're better off doing the combine in the UI.

Notes:

- Wrap case in `string_Agg()` function the "Case" statement is then wrapped in the string_agg() function and since we operate inside out just like math, the case is resolved 1st.
- added `GROUP BY` for non-aggregated element(s)
- eliminated `DISTINCT` as `GROUP BY` takes care of it so distinct is unneeded clutter.
- added additional sample data to show how multiple columns handled.
- eliminated pt.notes table as I'm not using it in my generated common table expression
- You will not need the "with notes as ()..."  Just the select after it and correct the `FROM` clause to yours

[dbfiddle.uk Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=00d55afc38e7a0c08e82a2981e898511)

More on this-->[How to concatenate string of a string field in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query)

```
WITH notes AS (
  SELECT 891090 Order_ID, False customer_billing,  false commander, true agent UNION ALL
  SELECT 891090, true, false, false UNION ALL
  SELECT 891091, false, true, false UNION ALL
  SELECT 891091, true, false, false)

SELECT
  n.order_id,
  string_Agg(CASE
    WHEN n.customer_billing = TRUE THEN 'AR (Customer Billing)'
    WHEN n.commander = TRUE THEN 'AP (Commander)'
    WHEN n.agent = TRUE THEN 'AP (Agent)'
    ELSE NULL
  END,', ') AS finance
FROM notes n
 WHERE
 n.order_id = 891090 AND
  (n.customer_billing = TRUE or n.commander = TRUE or n.agent = TRUE)
 GROUP BY ORDER_ID
```

Giving us:

```
+----------+---------------------------------------+
| order_id |                finance                |
+----------+---------------------------------------+
|   891091 | AP (Commander), AR (Customer Billing) |
|   891090 | AP (Agent), AR (Customer Billing)     |
+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This can have duplicate values in the comma separated string like "AP (Commander), AR (Customer Billing),  AR (Customer Billing)". Is there a way to eliminate the duplicate from the current output?

Comment: do you have sample data showing this problem for me?  I think distinct may work but I need to understand the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785084/issue-with-string-agg-with-distinct-in-postgres  `String_Agg(Distinct case...)`

Comment: Keep in mind we're starting to deal with edge cases that were not defined in the orginal scope of the question.  Other such things may pop-up!